# Find all URL's in a string in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building an app in Rails 3 and I need a method to extract all urls from a string and store them in a hash or something. I know I need to use regular expressions but I don't know where exactly to begin with them.

Also, I know about auto_link, but it doesn't quite do what I'm trying to achieve. I just simply need a hash of all the url's from a string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

"To collect all regex matches in a string into an array, pass the regexp object to the string's scan() method, e.g.: myarray = mystring.scan(/regex/)."

So you probably need strings that start with "http". [So check the docs for that :)](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html)

Comment: Thanks, and for anyone else that's wondering, this is the regex that I used:/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/

Answer (score 0):

I don't program in Ruby and I'm not very good with regex but maybe this will help you out:

http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/url-regex-t104809.html